# Buttons to be renamed by the user

Tags: vb.net, button, user-input, messagebox

I am having problems coding some of my buttons. This is what I've got so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim Button(12) As Button
Dim X As Integer

Private Sub EventName()
    Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
    Dim myValue As Object
    If Label4.Text = "Admin" Then
        ' Set prompt.
        Message = "Enter Product Name"
        ' Set title.
        title = "Product Name"
        defaultValue = ""   ' Set default value.

        'Display message, title, and default value.
        myValue = InputBox(Message, title, defaultValue)

        Button(X).Text = myValue
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button9.Click, Button8.Click, Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button2.Click, Button12.Click, Button11.Click, Button10.Click
    'Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
    'Dim myValue As Object
    For Me.X = 1 To 10

        >>>>>    <<<<<<<

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button(1) = Button1
    Button(2) = Button2
    Button(3) = Button3
    Button(4) = Button4
    Button(5) = Button5
    Button(6) = Button6
    Button(7) = Button7
    Button(8) = Button8
    Button(9) = Button9
    Button(10) = Button10
    Button(11) = Button11
    Button(12) = Button12
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do, is if I click button 7, an input box comes up for the user to input the button's name. No matter what I have tried between the `>>>>> <<<<<`, I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: What specifically have you tried between the `>>>>> <<<<<` that did not work?

Comment: I had the EventName() there and the just returned the buttons in order so if i click button 7 button 1 would be named then button 2 ect.

Comment: And was the code getting to that function? At what line did it break down? Were there any errors thrown? And for clarity, when you say button name, do you mean the name in code, or the caption on the button?

Comment: The caption on button and no got no eeror message and this is how i had it set

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click        Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
        Dim myValue As Object
        For Me.X = 1 To 10
            'need to work out

            If Label4.Text = "Admin" Then
                ' Set prompt.
                message = "Enter Product Name"
                ' Set title.
                title = "Product Name"
                defaultValue = ""   ' Set default value.

                'Display message, title, and default value.
                myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)

                Button(X).Text = myValue
            End If

Comment: See @LarsTech's answer. Look like he's got it, though his `InputBox` arguments don't quite match yours. Remove your loop and go straight to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a person to click on a button and change the text of that button?

If that is correct, something like this would work in your click method:

```
With DirectCast(sender, Button)
  .Text = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name", .Text)
End With
```

If every button needs that same input, then try something like this:

```
Dim value As String = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name")
For Each btn As Button In Buttons
  If btn IsNot Nothing Then
    btn.Text = value
  End If
Next
```

You should strongly consider moving away from using that Buttons array.  If you need to hold a reference of those buttons in a list, use a `List(of Button)` instead.

Comment: WOW i was looking way o arinto it lol that is so much easier thank you so much.

Comment: Just one more thing is there a way to use the Button name in a text box

Comment: @CraigEmerson I did that with the first version.  If all of the buttons say the same thing, then use a saved variable for that third parameter (which I omitted in the second version).

Comment: thank you for the help ive posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11691017/1557944 which follows on from this one and could do with a bit more help.