# Input a button's text into a text box

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox

Following on from my last Question [Buttons to be renamed by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11690108/1557944) which was answered quickly and helped a lot.

At the moment I have got this code, which I need to have on 100's of buttons.

What I need to know is how to use the text from the button to put into the different text boxes that requires them.

```
    If Label4.Text = "Admin" Then
        With DirectCast(sender, Button)
            .Text = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name", .Text)
        End With
    Else
        Me.TransactionBindingSource.AddNew()

        Product_NameTextBox.Text = >>>>>>Button name<<<<<<<<
        Try
            Me.ProductTableAdapter.FillByProductName(Me.Database1DataSet.Product, Product_NameTextBox.Text)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        ProductTextBox.Text = >>>>>>>Button2.Text<<<<<<<<
        GroupTextBox.Text = GroupTextBox1.Text
        AmountTextBox.Text = AmountTextBox1.Text
        PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox1.Text
        TimeTextBox.Text = TimeOfDay
        DateTextBox.Text = DateString

        Me.Validate()
        Me.TransactionBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TransactionTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet)

        Timer2.Enabled = True
        TransNameLB.Items.Add(>>>>>>>Button2.Text<<<<<<<<)
        TransPriceLB.Items.Add(PriceTextBox.Text)

        Dim sum As Double
        For x As Integer = 0 To TransPriceLB.Items.Count - 1
            sum += Val(TransPriceLB.Items.Item(x).ToString)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString

        QTYDrinksTB.Text = TransNameLB.Items.Count
    End If

End Sub
```

Everything works apart from the bits between `>>> <<<`, where I need to get the button that is clicked and return the text from the button into the text boxes/list box.

I have 100's of buttons that need this code.

Comment: Hello Craig, Can you please link your post to this one? Also, please explain in greater detail what you are asking. You may also want to place a "NEED HELP HERE" in comments (') above the code where you need help, as well as the line it appears on, so we may better answer your question(s). ~JOL

Comment: I need help with what to put inbetween the >>>>>> <<<<<<< the bits between need to get the text from the button and put it in the text box.

Comment: FYI, it really appears that you are using VB.NET, not VBA. There are some major differences between the two.

Comment: im using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express

Comment: Right, and that is *REALLY* VB.NET. ;-) VBA is specifically related to the VB used within Office Applications such as Outlook, Excel, and Word. While much of the syntax is the same, there are things that don't work in both (for example `x += y` syntax).

Comment: ahhhhhh ok i see sorry bout that ill remember that in future lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `With DirectCast(sender, Button)` from your previous question, which can also be used to help with your other parts. For example:

```
If Label4.Text = "Admin" Then
    With DirectCast(sender, Button)
        .Text = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name", .Text)
    End With

Else
    Me.TransactionBindingSource.AddNew()

    With DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Product_NameTextBox.Text = .Text

    Try
        Me.ProductTableAdapter.FillByProductName(Me.Database1DataSet.Product, Product_NameTextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    ProductTextBox.Text = .Text
    GroupTextBox.Text = GroupTextBox1.Text
    AmountTextBox.Text = AmountTextBox1.Text
    PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox1.Text
    TimeTextBox.Text = TimeOfDay
    DateTextBox.Text = DateString

    Me.Validate()
    Me.TransactionBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TransactionTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet)

    Timer2.Enabled = True
    TransNameLB.Items.Add(.Text)
    TransPriceLB.Items.Add(PriceTextBox.Text)

    End With

    Dim sum As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To TransPriceLB.Items.Count - 1
        sum += Val(TransPriceLB.Items.Item(x).ToString)
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString

    QTYDrinksTB.Text = TransNameLB.Items.Count
End If
```