# Why is it that when i close the program and reload it all my user inputed button names have gone?

Tags: vb.net, button, user-input

Hi me again I've come across another problem following my last 2 questions. [Buttons to be renamed by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11690108/1557944) and [Input a button's text into a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11691017/1557944).

What happens is when label4 is admin when you click the button an input box appears asking for the button name and if label4 is anything else then it adds the text of the button to different boxes.

This all works fine the problem I'm having is when i close the program and then re open it all the buttons text has been removed.

So in short what im asking is how t\do I make it save to the button so that if I close the program and re open it the text stays on all the buttons.

The Code I have for the button is.

```
Dim Button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

If Label4.Text = "Admin" Then
    With DirectCast(sender, Button)
        .Text = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name", .Text)
    End With
Else
    Me.TransactionBindingSource.AddNew()
    Product_NameTextBox.Text = Button.Text

    Try
        Me.ProductTableAdapter.FillByProductName(Me.Database1DataSet.Product, Product_NameTextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    ProductTextBox.Text = Button.Text
    GroupTextBox.Text = GroupTextBox1.Text
    AmountTextBox.Text = AmountTextBox1.Text
    PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox1.Text
    TimeTextBox.Text = TimeOfDay
    DateTextBox.Text = DateString

    Me.Validate()

    Me.TransactionBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TransactionTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet)
    Timer2.Enabled = True
    TransNameLB.Items.Add(Button.Text)
    TransPriceLB.Items.Add(PriceTextBox.Text)

    Dim sum As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To TransPriceLB.Items.Count - 1
        sum += Val(TransPriceLB.Items.Item(x).ToString)
    Next

    TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString
    QTYDrinksTB.Text = TransNameLB.Items.Count
End If
```

Thanking you in advance for any help provided

Craig

Comment: could you save the values to a file, and read them back when the program runs again?

Comment: Are you in Visual Basic? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4kyezf(v=vs.80).aspx explains how writing to files is done. You can write the button values to the file when a user inputs them, and open the file to read the values back out when the program runs again.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? The concept or implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Mark Hall said (excellent answer!), VB can do it all automagically for you. You have to set up a binding to the application setting.

1. Go to the properties tab for your button
2. Expand out the (ApplicationSettings) property
3. Click in the Text area. A dropdown will appear, choose New
4. In the Dialog that pops up, give it a name and make sure the scope
   is User

Now, the app will automatically remember the text you've set, and reload it on app startup

[image]

Comment: +1 I knew that I had done something like that before... just could not remember where. :)

Comment: No probs. I've not ever used this myself, but I remember being impressed that it was all magically done for you :)

Comment: Is there a quicker way to do this cause i got 100's of buttons or have i got to do it 1 by 1.

Comment: If you don't mind futzing with the .designer code, it looks like it'd be pretty easy to copy + paste + modify the line that it adds about `.DataBindings` and `.Text`. For hundreds of buttons I'd look at Mark's answer, at least using it you only have to enter the settings by hand, the rest of the code where he loops the controls will save you some work

Comment: kk ty for all the help both of you ill crack on and set up all these settings lol

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Vb.net one of the ways you can persist your user settings is by using the [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/saa62613.aspx) object.  This is kind of a simplistic example but should give you the idea.

First I created a Setting with the same name as the Buttons Name by right clicking on the project and going to the Project Propertys settings tab.

[image]

I then saved it in the Button Click event like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    With DirectCast(sender, Button)
        .Text = InputBox("Button Name", "Button Name", .Text)
        My.MySettings.Default.Item(Button1.Name) = .Text
        My.MySettings.Default.Save()
    End With
End Sub
```

The next step is to iterate through all of the controls in the Forms Control Collection to find the Buttons to put the saved text into.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is Button Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.MySettings.Default.Item(cntrl.Name).ToString) Then 'Check to make sure there is Data there
                cntrl.Text = My.MySettings.Default.Item(cntrl.Name).ToString
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

or you could also use the button name explicitly.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.MySettings.Default.Item(Button1.Name).ToString) Then
        Button1.Text = My.MySettings.Default.Item(Button1.Name).ToString
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have given it a try but got an eeror message on running saying the settings property 'Button19' was not found.

Comment: Did you add a setting called Button19 to your project --> Propertys --> Setttings ?